# Create group when another model is created

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have a model **workspace** and and I use the model **group** from django to apply permissions.
However, whenever an user create a workspace I want the workspace to create a group as well.

This is what I tried :

```
 instance = form.save(commit=False)
                instance.token = uuid4()
                x = uuid4()
                groupworkspace = Group
                groupworkspace = Group.objects.create('GROUP TEST')
                instance.join_token = str(x)[:8]
                instance.join_token_date = datetime.now()
                instance.save()
                instance.members.set([request.user]
```

Now everything work except that I does not create the group, instead it return.

> create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

[`create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#create) method accepts only keyword arguments, but you are trying to pass positional argument. To fix change code to this:

```
groupworkspace = Group.objects.create(name='GROUP TEST')
```